# How to escape spaces in URLs before page rendered in java

Tags: jsp, url, w3c, spaces

I have links in the project, with render with spaces:
`href="/plugins/configure/Poulpe Auth Plugin"` - this is an example from page source.

Of course browser encodes spaces as %20 before send it to server, but I have an error in W3C validator:

```
 Bad value /plugins/configure/Poulpe Auth Plugin for attribute href on element a: Whitespace in path component. Use %20 in place of spaces.
```

As I saw in other resources, in similar situations spaces were replaced with '-', '+' or '_'.
I'm not sure I can rewrite spaces in data before saving to db, so should I handle them before set parameters to request? Could somebody please explain me where should I handle query parameters spaces before display them in urls?

Comment: Use org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils to HTML escaping.

Comment: I've tried, but this approach didn't solve my issue

Comment: Why are you using whitespaces in your project urls?

Comment: On which side, you want to handle whitespaces? Either you are fetching your urls from database or getting from UI to store them in database?

Comment: Actually we using name of object - ${plugin.name} in part when we create url:
 `href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/plugins/configure/${plugin.name}"`

Names of objects can include whitespaces. I'm not sure we should save names without whitespaces and I have no idea where and how to rewrite those before using them in urls.

Comment: This is terrible, you are mixing jsp-scriplet and jQuery code. I am unable to understand. What is plugin? And if you are creating url based on your server-side plugin object then your pattern is wrong.

try:
href = '"<%=pageContext.request.contextPath %>"/plugins/configure/"<%=plugin.name %>"'

Comment: You're wrong about mixing jsp-scriplet and jQuery code. Your suggestion is a pure scriplet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41820/discussion-between-trierra-and-parkash-kumar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the decision:

```
<a href="<spring:url value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/plugins/configure/{pluginName}">
                                <spring:param name="pluginName" value="${plugin.name}" />
                            </spring:url>"
                                 title="<spring:message code='label.plugins.plugin.configure.hint'/>">
                                <spring:message code="label.plugins.plugin.configure"/>
                            </a>
```

And I've got:

```
<a href="/plugins/configure/Poulpe%20Auth%20Plugin" data-original-title="Press to configure this plugin">Configure</a>
```